# Python match a column name based on a column value in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, match

Apologies if this is a duplicate of some sort, I looked at 20 different questions, but none of them helped me. If someone can point me to a question that answers this, I'll happily delete my question.

I have two dataframes, the first is called df_full long list of various columns, one of which is called 'Industry' and has the strings of various Industries. `df_full['Industry'].head()` is:

| INDEX | Industry |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Service |
| 1 | Service |
| 2 | Trade |
| 3 | Service |
| 4 | Manufacturing |

My second dataframe is called df_industry and has quantiles based on each of the industries. `df_industry['profit_sales']` is:

| Industry |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Financial | 0.25 | 0.025616 |
|  | 0.50 | 0.219343 |
|  | 0.75 | 0.410408 |
| Manufacturing | 0.25 | -0.012373 |
|  | 0.50 | 0.002032 |
|  | 0.75 | 0.010331 |
| Service | 0.25 | -0.012660 |
|  | 0.50 | 0.003375 |
|  | 0.75 | 0.064102 |
| Trade | 0.25 | -0.102178 |
|  | 0.50 | 0.001715 |
|  | 0.75 | 0.018705 |
| Transport | 0.25 | -0.042755 |
|  | 0.50 | -0.042755 |
|  | 0.75 | 0.056487 |

I am trying to create a new column for my first dataframe with the 0.5 quantile according to the industry in column industry.

Thus my new output table should look like, `df_full[['Industry','quantile_05']].head()`

| INDEX | Industry | quantile_05 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Service | 0.003375 |
| 1 | Service | 0.003375 |
| 2 | Trade | 0.001715 |
| 3 | Service | 0.003375 |
| 4 | Manufacturing | 0.002032 |

I have currently tried to no avail:
`df_full['quantile_05'] = df_full.apply(lambda x: df_industry['profit_sales'][df_full['Industry'][x]][0.5] ,axis=1)`

Comment: Filter your df_industry so you only have the 0.5 rows, rename, and join. If you post your data, you may get a more explicit answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can do a map:

```
df_full['quantile_05'] = df_full['Industry'].map(df_industry['profit_sales'].unstack()[0.5])
```

Output:

```
             Industry  quantile_05
INDEX                             
0             Service     0.003375
1             Service     0.003375
2               Trade     0.001715
3             Service     0.003375
4       Manufacturing     0.002032
```

If you want all three quantiles, you can do a `merge` as suggested by Kyle:

```
df_full.merge(df_industry['profit_sales'].unstack(),
          left_on=['Industry'], 
          right_index=True,
          how='left')
```

Output:

```
             Industry      0.25       0.5      0.75
INDEX                                              
0             Service -0.012660  0.003375  0.064102
1             Service -0.012660  0.003375  0.064102
2               Trade       NaN  0.001715  0.018705
3             Service -0.012660  0.003375  0.064102
4       Manufacturing -0.012373  0.002032  0.010331
```

Comment: Wow somehow I've missed that you can give a Series (or dict) to map, good suggestion.